# Changing the name of multiple files based on an index

Tags: python

I currently have several hundred pdf files with file names that I would like to change.

The current names of the files don't really follow a pattern, however I have a Excel file with what the current file name is and what the new file name is that I want for a specific file. This looks similar to this:

[image: excel index]

I am looking for a way in python to rename all of my files (about 500) according to my excel index.

What I tried:

```
import os

path = 'C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Project\\'
files = os.listdir(path)

for file in files:
   os.rename(os.path.join(path, file), os.path.join(path, '00' + file + '.pdf'))
```

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? Show us some code.

Comment: import os
path = 'C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Project\\'
files = os.listdir(path)
for file in files:
   os.rename(os.path.join(path, file), os.path.join(path, '00' + file + '.pdf'))

Comment: But generally: load the contents of that excel file as a dictionary (if you save the table as csv, it will be easy to load without additional libs) or even just pairs, then just go through all of it and try renaming (I said "try" because it's better to wrap it in a `try`).

Answer (score 1):

If you can save the excel file as csv, this should work

```py
import os
import csv

path = 'C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Project\\'

with open('my_csv.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader) # Skip first row
    for line in reader:
        src = os.path.join(path, line[0])
        dest = os.path.join(path, line[1])
        os.rename(src, dest)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are really close!

You need to iterate over the names in your `xlsx` file. One simple way is to load the data using [`pandas.read_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) and finally iterate over the `source` and `dest` column and renaming the file.

You can use [`os.pth.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to create the full path from a given folder and a given file.

Here the code:

```
# Import module
import os                   # Rename file
import pandas as pd         # read csv

# Your different folders
path_folder = r'C:\Users\Desktop\Project'
path_csv = r'C:\Users\Desktop\Project\csv_file.xlsx'

# Load data
df = pd.read_excel(path_csv)
print(df)
#   Current file name Desired file name
# 0             a.pdf           001.pdf
# 1             b.pdf           002.pdf
# 2             c.pdf           003.pdf

# Iterate over each row of the dataframe
for old_name, new_name in zip(df["Current file name"], df["Desired file name"]):
    # Create source path and destination path
    source_file = os.path.join(path_folder, old_name)
    dest_file = os.path.join(path_folder, new_name)
    # Rename the current file using the source path (old name) 
    # and the destination path (new name)
    os.rename(source_file, dest_file )
```

Excel file used:

[image]

Hope that helps !

Answer (score 0):

Provided you have table with names, you can use the following code:

```
import os

names = '''a.pdf    001.pdf
b.pdf   002.pdf
c.pdf   003.pdf'''

os.chdir(r'C:\Users\Desktop\Project')
for line in names.splitlines(False):
    old, new = line.split()
    os.rename(old, new)
```

You can copy table from Excel to this piece of code

If you don't care about table, you can try

```
import os
from itertools import count

numbers = count(1)

os.chdir(r'C:\Users\Desktop\Project')
for old in os.listdir('.'):
    if not old.endswith('.pdf'):
        continue
    new = '%03d.pdf' % next(numbers)
    os.rename(old, new)
```